# AJAX data forcing FancyBox modal to be larger than browser window

Tags: jquery, ajax, fancybox

I have a link to a potentially large table of data:

```
<a class="tabledata" href="table.php">View data</a>
```

In the head of the page I load jQuery and [FancyBox](http://fancybox.net/) and then use the following to pull just the table fragment from the dummy HTML page:

```
$("a.tabledata").fancybox({
    'type': 'ajax',
    'ajax': { 
        dataFilter: function(data){
            return $(data).find('table');
        }
     }
});
```

In `table.php` I have a large table of data. Below is the unstyled dummy I've been using to try and debug this issue:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Dummy table</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="transactions" class="panel">
    <h4>Transactions</h4>
    <table class="data_list">
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th><th>Row class</th><th>Hash</th>
      </tr>
<?php
$c = 0;
while ( $c < 100 ) : ?>
      <tr class="<?php echo ( $c++ % 2 == 1 ) ? 'odd' : 'even'; ?>">
        <td><?php echo $c; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo ( $c % 2 == 1 ) ? 'odd' : 'even'; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo md5( $c ); ?></td>
      </tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Small tables are displayed perfectly.

If I load the large table as a FancyBox iFrame, it's positioned correctly within the browser window, and there is a scrollbar on the right.

If I load the large table through FancyBox AJAX (which I need to do in order to isolate the required page fragment), the FancyBox modal extends way beyond the bottom of the browser window -- even beyond the background overlay.

How can I force AJAX FancyBox modals to size themselves correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can force the size of the fancybox:

```
$.fancybox(
    '<p>BOX CONTENT</p>',
    {
        'autoDimensions'    : false,
        'width'             : 800,
        'height'            : 600,
        'scrolling'        : 'yes' //or auto depending on preference
    }
);
```

I assume that forcing the size to "smaller" than the content will activate a scroll method. Check the Fancybox Docs on this issue.

Given your example:

```
$("a.tabledata").fancybox({
    'type': 'ajax',
    'ajax': { 
                dataFilter: function(data){
                    return $(data).find('table');
                }
            },
    'width':800,
    'height':600,
    'autoDimensions':false,
    'scrolling':'yes' //or auto depending on preference
});
```

`autoDimensions` defaults to `true` and resizes the modal box to fit the content, if the content is massive and goes off the page, the modal box will fit it and thus go off the page. Setting the height and width of the box and then disabling `autoDimensions` will allow the sizing to work.

**Update:**

I've just had another idea. If you wrap the table in the html with a div and style the div to specific dimensions with `overflow:auto` then call the div into the ajax instead of the table, it should work.

There are many examples here: http://fancybox.net/blog

Comment: Have you successfully tested that? I tried it and it seemed to make no difference. The FancyBox api says that `width` and `height` are for content types `iframe` and `swf`.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to copy the `autoDimensions` property across. If you set the height and width and then set `autoDimensions` to `false` it works. Not tested but it works according to the documentation, which I suppose is as good a source as any :)

Comment: You, sir, are a legend. Here's what I ended up using (I didn't want to alter the HTML of the actual page): `return $(data).filter('#transactions').css({ 'max-height': $(window).height()-100+'px', 'overflow': 'auto' });`

Comment: Nice twist on things, (window height - 100) hadn't thought of that. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

I don't usually post here, but this one was driving me crazy also.

The way I resolved it was to set fitToView to false and turn off scrolling.

```
jQuery(".various").fancybox({
    maxWidth    : 950,
    maxHeight   : 2000,
    fitToView   : false,
    width       : '88%',
    height      : 1300,
    autoSize    : false,
    closeClick  : false,
    openEffect  : 'none',
    closeEffect : 'none',
    autoDimensions  : false,
    scrolling   : 'no'
});
```